# Elevating go code to root? Best practices?

Tags: linux, go, linux-kernel

I have a Go web app on Linux that needs to manipulate the networking stack. The code to do the manipulation is in a Go package and needs to be run with root privileges - e.g. if it's not sudo'd, it fails with a permission failure.

However, I don't want to run the entire web app with elevated privileges. Just the code that needs it. Do I have to call (exec.Command) it in a separate file and use suid? Or is there a more elegant approach?

What are the best practices?

Comment: Having only a bit of code run with special permissions, seems like an antipattern to me (that doesn't mean it's incorrect though). I might just be old school, but adding the user that runs your app to (for Debian based OSes) the `netdev` group seems like standard practice.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Linux Capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and give your process minimal set of capabilities it needs to accomplish the task (likely CAP_NET_ADMIN). Once code reaches the point where all was set your process can drop the privilege(s) given by assigned capability(ies).

Go package [cap](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/cap) provides bindings for Linux libcap to perform this task.

Here is very well commented Go example of program doing privileged thing and then dropping privilege using the package linked above: https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/getting-started-with-go/building-go-programs-that-manipulate-capabilities?authuser=0

Note that process still needs to be given initial set of capabilities before executed (e.g. using setcap like `sudo setcap cap_net_admin+ep ./path/to/binary`).